# Destructor being called early

Tags: c++

I have a queue class wherein I'm trying to dynamically allocate 3 "sample" objects and place them into a queue, and then dequeue and delete them. But the destructor for the sample objects:

```
~Sample() { cout << "Destructing Sample object " << id << "\n"; }
```

Is for some reason being called when I try to put the objects on the queue.

```
int main()
{
   Sample *samp1;
   Sample *samp2;
   Sample *samp3;
   Queue<Sample> sQa(3);
   samp1 = new Sample(1);
   samp2 = new Sample(2);
   samp3 = new Sample(3);

   cout << "Adding 3 Sample objects to queue...\n";

   sQa.put(*samp1);
   sQa.put(*samp2);
   sQa.put(*samp3);

   cout << "Dequeing and destroying the objects...\n";

   for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
   {
       delete &sQa.get();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Adding 3 sample objects to queue...
Destructing Sample object 1
Destructing Sample object 2
Destructing Sample object 3
Dequeing and destroying the objects...
Destructing Sample object 1
```

And then the program crashes. Anyone know why this might be? Also, here is the put function in case it is necessary. (the queue class is a template)

```
void put(Qtype data) 
{
    if(putloc == size) 
    {
        cout << " -- Queue is full.\n";
        return;
    }

    putloc++;
    q[putloc] = data;   
}
```

Comment: You should read a C++ book to understand the difference between automatic storage and dynamic storage, and what is the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference (or pointers). It is a hard topic that can be blissfully ignored in most other languages, so it need be studied specifically.

Comment: Why is this Q being close voted? You not liking the question is not a good enough reason to close it. The Q has all the information required to answer it convincingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of your problem

```
delete &sQa.get();
```

You're deleting something which is irrelevant to the allocated objects by `new`.

The correct way is something like below:

```
Queue<Sample*> sQa(3);
samp1 = new Sample(1);
samp2 = new Sample(2);
samp3 = new Sample(3);

sQa.put(samp1);
sQa.put(samp2);
sQa.put(samp3);

cout << "Dequeing and destroying the objects...\n";

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
   delete sQa.get();
}
```

Note: it's better to use smart pointers such as `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` instead bare pointers.

Answer (score 10):

Your code causes Undefined behavior. It calls `delete` on a object which was not dynamically allocated using `new`.

With:

```
sQa.put(*samp1);
```

You store a copy of the dynamically allocated member in `sQa`. You lost the pointer to dynamically allocated objects once you copied the object by value.

The solution is to use smart pointer as the container element and let RAII do all the hard work of memory management for you.

Comment: A better solution might be to leave the container as it is (storing objects), and not mess around with dynamic allocation at all.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: For sure. But looking at OPs sample program, it seems more like an educational exercise than attempt to solve a real world problem. But good to mention it though.

Answer (score 1):

Unless Qtype is a typedef, your put() function specifies its parameter should be passed by copy. Whenever you call it, it will call Sample's copy constructor to create a temporary object.

Answer (score 1):

You code allocates objects; copies them into the queue; retrieves copies from the queue; and tries to delete those copies. The original objects are leaked (since you don't `delete samp1` etc.), and the final objects can't be deleted since they weren't created with `new`.

The destructors you're seeing are from temporary objects created while you copy the allocated objects into the queue; the crash is the undefined behaviour you get from deleting the wrong object.

Since the queue contains objects, not pointers, there is no need to mess around with dynamic allocation at all:

```
cout << "Adding 3 Sample objects to queue...\n";

sQa.put(Sample(1));
sQa.put(Sample(2));
sQa.put(Sample(3));

cout << "Dequeing and destroying the objects...\n";

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
   sQa.get();
}
```

If you want to experiment with dynamic allocation, then you should modify the queue to store pointers; but remember that it's very difficult to manage dynamic objects without the help of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) so don't try this in any code that needs to be reliable.

Comment: You might add that the early destruction he's seeing is probably due to a temporarly being created somewhere in the `sQa.put`.  That temporary will be destructed.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Good point, I forgot to answer the actual question.